# SQL Server fetch columns based on specific row numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I need to select last one year orders based on email (billing address email address). I need to show order number, shipping first name, shipping last name, billing address email id and item descriptions along with submitted date. Same address table use to store shipping (ship_to 1) and billing address (ship_to always 0). The email field in shipping address is optional and if both the addresses match only billing address is written to DB.

**Address**:

```
Order_num first_name  last_name    email        ship_to_num      
-----------------------------------------------------------
ord1       abc          abc        abc@c.com      0
ord1       cdf          ccc        XXc@m.com      1
```

I wrote a initial query like below:

```
select 
    addr.first_name, addr.last_name, addr.order_num, addr.Update_Date_Time,
    ord.Order_Amt, item.Item_Desc
from 
    ADDR addr 
inner join 
    ORDER ord on ord.Order_num = addr.Order_Num
inner join 
    ITEM item on ord.Order_num = item.Order_Num
where 
    addr.Order_Num in (select Order_num 
                       from TOEADDR addr 
                       where addr.ShipTo_Num = 0 
                         and addr.EM_EMAIL_ADDR = 'avc@abc.com'
                         and addr.Update_Date_Time > DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())) 
order by  
    addr.Update_Date_Time desc
```

Is there any way I can add this logic to above query:

```
 (SELECT TOP 1 First_Name, LAST_NAME FROM ADDR ORDER BY ShipTo_Num ASC)
```

Thanks, with CTE it worked like a charm. Below is the final query:

```
 ;with cte_addr
 AS
 (SELECT First_Name,LAST_NAME,  EM_EMAIL_ADDR, order_num,Update_Date_Time,ShipTo_Num
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_num ORDER BY ShipTo_Num desc) as ROWID
 FROM ADDR 
 ) 
 SELECT addr.first_name , addr.last_name, addr.order_num, addr.Update_Date_Time,
 ord.Order_Amt, item.Item_Desc
 FROM cte_addr addr
  inner join ORDER ord on ord.Order_num = addr.Order_Num
 inner join ITEM item on ord.Order_num = item.Order_Num
   WHERE addr.ROWID =1  and 
 addr.Order_Num in(
  select Order_num from ADDR billAddress where
  billAddress.ShipTo_Num = 0 and billAddress.EM_EMAIL_ADDR = 'afv@abv.com'
  and billAddress.Update_Date_Time > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 

 ) 
order by addr.Update_Date_Time desc
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Did you try to write a `subquery` and `join` to make your expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE to achieve it.  You can write query like below.  This can be a sample query for the logic you are looking for

```
;with cte_addr
 AS
 (SELECT First_Name,LAST_NAME, email EM_EMAIL_ADDR, order_num,Update_Date_Time,ShipTo_Num
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY First_Name,LAST_NAME ORDER BY ShipTo_Num) ROWID
 FROM ADDR 
 ) 
 SELECT addr.first_name , addr.last_name, addr.order_num, addr.Update_Date_Time,
 ord.Order_Amt, item.Item_Desc
 FROM cte_addr addr
 inner join ORDER ord on ord.Order_num = addr.Order_Num
inner join ITEM item on ord.Order_num = item.Order_Num
 WHERE t.ROWID =1 
and addr.Order_Num in(
select Order_num from TOEADDR addr where
addr.ShipTo_Num = 0 and addr.EM_EMAIL_ADDR = 'avc@avc.com'
and addr.Update_Date_Time > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
 ) 
order by addr.Update_Date_Time desc
```